# How to dict(zip) for every item on list?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
kws = [1, 2, 3]

ab = dict(zip(['keyword:'], kws))
print ab
```

But it only returns: `{'keyword:': 1}`

I want to make it return: `{'keyword:': 1, 'keyword:': 2, 'keyword:': 3}`

Comment: dictionary can't have same `key `

Comment: What you want is not a valid dictionary. A dictionary must have unique keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vignesh Kalai's comment is correct, but if you just want tuples, try:

```
ab = zip((['keyword'] * len(kws)), kws)
```

Answer (score 2):

python dictionaries don't support multiple keys which is what you are trying to do, but you can have a key mapped to a list. So you could have

```
{keyword: [1, 2, 3]}
```

just by doing

```
kws = [1,2,3]
ab = {}
ab['Keyword'] = kws
print ab

{'Keyword': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Dictionary can't have same key.

Sorry, it's principle of dictionary. You question is requiring a invalid result.

I know everyone doesn't like your question.

I recommend you make `list-tuple object` to keep your data structure. Let's try to change the method.

```
print [('keyword', kw) for kw in kws]
# [('keyword', 1), ('keyword', 2), ('keyword', 3)]
```

So, it can simulate key-value pair. I think it can satisfy your needed.